# How can I change the author of commits in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had a typo in my git user.email (`user.email` = `examplemail@gmail.com` instead of `example.email@gmail.com`), resulting in my pushes to Bitbucket not correctly attributing them to me. These commits are now released into production, so amending the author on each commit in previous branches isn't ideal.

How can I update the author of these commits in Bitbucket?

Comment: You said, "amending the author on each commit in previous branches isn't ideal". I think you have to be willing and able to either amend (rewrite) those commits, or just let it go and fix it for all new commits. (Or perhaps change your email in bitbucket to be the wrong email, but I doubt you'd want to keep it that way moving forward...)

Comment: Yeah, might just have to let it go. Thought it was worth the shot though, in case there is just a db query I can get the bitbucket admins to run, or something

Comment: Maybe it's possible to associate an invalid email with your account (I doubt bitbucket would allow it but at least it's technically possible). But as for commits in a repo, you can't change anything about a commit without changing its hash (commit ID). Once you do that you have to rewrite all child commits from that point.

Comment: Nice one! See also https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html. I knew about the Plus but not the dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change anything about Git commits without rewriting them, and subsequently all child commits after that. In Bitbucket it's possible to [add additional email aliases to your account](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-email-aliases/), however, you'll need to be able to receive an email at that address to confirm it.

As a side note, with Gmail email addresses in particular, [periods are optional](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en), so first.last@gmail.com is the same as firstlast@gmail.com. If the only difference is a missing period, you may be in luck because you can confirm the "incorrect" email address.